# How to make some text overlap other text without position absolute

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I have two text fields inside a 100% width flex row. One is positioned on the left and the other on the right. I want the text on the right to overlap/cover the text on the left when the container (window) is resized (smaller) from the right.

Solutions must not use absolute positioning. The left-text has a left margin that the right-text must stop at. The text container is purposefully a row of 100% width.

Fiddle is not the best platform for layout and resizing testing, but https://jsfiddle.net/Lcjcyp4g/6/

The position:abs solution is commented out in the flex code below for completeness. Please ignore the behavior on resize-right -- our only focus is text overlap on resize-left.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container--text">
    <div class="left">Left Text</div>
    <!-- <div class="container--right"> -->
       <div class="right">Right Text</div>
    <!-- </div> -->
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>



   html, body {
    height: 100vh;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #D7CCC8;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    min-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:20px;
    height: 14px;
    max-height:14px;
}

.container--text {
    height: 14px;
    max-height:14px;
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.left {
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    flex-shrink:1;
}

/* This is not a viable soln because there is no boundary left for the pos:absolute element without JS*/
.container--right {
  /*height: 14px;
  background-color: #D7CCC8;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  */
}
.right {
    white-space: nowrap;
    justify-self:flex-end;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:20px;
    background-color:#BCAAA4;
    color: #616161;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: ?? is this what you try to do https://jsfiddle.net/Lcjcyp4g/4/ .

Comment: Do you want the text on the right to be over the top when scaled? Or the text on the left to disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to add `width: 0;min-width: 0;` to the left text to make the left part with no size thus the text will overflow. Then due to `white-space:nowrap` you won't see any visual changes but the right text will be able to cover it.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container--text {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  padding: 10px 0;
  animation: change 2s infinite linear alternate;
}

.left {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.right {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #BCAAA4;
  color: #616161;
}

@keyframes change {
 from{width:500px;}
 to{width:230px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container--text">
  <div class="left">Leeeeeeeeeeeft Text</div>
  <div class="right">Rigggggggggggggggght Text</div>
</div>
```

Or you can omit the `width:0` and use `overflow:hidden` to hide the text when its container will shrink:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container--text {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  padding: 10px 0;
  animation: change 2s infinite linear alternate;
}

.left {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  min-width: 0;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.right {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #BCAAA4;
  color: #616161;
}

@keyframes change {
  from { width: 500px;}
  to { width: 230px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container--text">
  <div class="left">Leeeeeeeeeeeft Text</div>
  <div class="right">Rigggggggggggggggght Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent. Your solution was exact once I added a higher z-index to the right text. Please explain your reasoning if you don't mind :)

Comment: @user2355058 it relies on overflow ;) making width:0 the text is overflowing the left part and the left part has no size so taking no space, thus the left can be above the overflowed text

Comment: @user2355058 I added more explanation, hope it's more clear ;)

Comment: Excellent help!

Comment: The fiddle has been updated with the code from the accepted answer -- How can we get `text-overflow: ellipsis` to work on the left-text?

Comment: I would like left-text to have ellipsis from when right-text begins to cover it and until left-text is hidden.